# How move/copy a file from folder outside of VSCode workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

1. I have an open folder in VSCode, eg `/folders/project1`, this is my workspace.
2. I want to add a file from outside of this folder, eg `/media/files/file1`.

I wish there was a VSCode command that displays a file picker that I can select any file on my computer's memory, and that file ends up in a folder opened as workspace.

For example:
3. In VSCode select the file `/media/files/file1` and it lands in workspace as `/folders/project1/file1`

How to do it? I can't find anything.

Of course I know I can do this manually in the file manager, but I want to do it without leaving VSCode.

Comment: [Import file to folder - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tiagoaspina.import-file-to-folder)

Comment: @DavidPostill Overall ok, but you can not add to the root folder. :/

Comment: Adding to the root folder has started working. I add this as a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension works exactly as I need it to:
[Import file to folder - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tiagoaspina.import-file-to-folder)

It also works to add to root folder.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to this (at least without add-ons as one of the commenters suggested) is dragging and dropping a file to one of the folders in open in the VS Code explorer.

You can consider File Explorer to be the "file picker" you wish for.
**Bonus:**
If you are using Windows, <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> opens the file explorer if that'll speed you up ;)

[image]

Comment: I do not like it.
Here anyway you need to open the file manager to enter the source folder.